# Getting owner of file from smb share, by using python on linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, smb, cifs, cacls

I need to find out for a script I'm writing who is the true owner of a file in an smb share (mounted using `mount -t cifs` of course on my server and using `net use` through windows machines).

Turns out it is a real challenge finding this information out using python on a linux server.

I tried using many many smb libraries (such as smbprotocol, smbclient and others), nothing worked.
I find few solutions for windows, they all use pywin32 or another windows specific package.
And I also managed to do it from bash using `smbcalcs` but couldn't do it cleanly but using `subprocess.popen('smbcacls')`..

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was unbelievably not a trivial task, and unfortunately the answer isn't simple as I hoped it would be..

I'm posting this answer if someone will be stuck with this same problem in the future, but hope maybe someone would post a better solution earlier

In order to find the owner I used [this library with its examples](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html):

```py
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

conn = SMBConnection(username='<username>', password='<password>', domain='<domain>', my_name='<some pc name>', remote_name='<server name>')
conn.connect('<server name>')

sec_att = conn.getSecurity('<share name>', r'\some\file\path')
owner_sid = sec_att.owner
```

The problem is that `pysmb` package will only give you the owner's SID and not his name.
In order to get his name you need to [make an ldap query like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122215/python-ldap3-code-to-get-username-from-sid) (reposting the code):

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
from ldap3.utils.conv import escape_bytes

s = Server('my_server', get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(s, 'my_user', 'my_password')
c.bind()

binary_sid = b'....'  # your sid must be in binary format

c.search('my_base', '(objectsid=' + escape_bytes(binary_sid) + ')', attributes=['objectsid', 'samaccountname'])
print(c.entries)
```

But of course nothing will be easy, it took me hours to find a way to convert a string SID to binary SID in python, [and in the end this solved it](https://github.com/sspreitzer/python-sid/blob/e52d9dbbf2f44e37381e9b0b1ab67d85eddb9aa7/src/sid/lib.py#L81):

```py
# posting the needed functions and omitting the class part
def byte(strsid):
    '''
    Convert a SID into bytes
        strdsid - SID to convert into bytes
    '''
    sid = str.split(strsid, '-')
    ret = bytearray()
    sid.remove('S')
    for i in range(len(sid)):
        sid[i] = int(sid[i])
    sid.insert(1, len(sid)-2)
    ret += longToByte(sid[0], size=1)
    ret += longToByte(sid[1], size=1)
    ret += longToByte(sid[2], False, 6)
    for i in range(3, len(sid)):
        ret += cls.longToByte(sid[i])
    return ret

def byteToLong(byte, little_endian=True):
    '''
    Convert bytes into a Python integer
        byte - bytes to convert
        little_endian - True (default) or False for little or big endian
    '''
    if len(byte) > 8:
        raise Exception('Bytes too long. Needs to be <= 8 or 64bit')
    else:
        if little_endian:
            a = byte.ljust(8, b'\x00')
            return struct.unpack('<q', a)[0]
        else:
            a = byte.rjust(8, b'\x00')
            return struct.unpack('>q', a)[0]
```

... AND finally you have the full solution! enjoy :(

Comment: Damn, that's bit shuffling for basic functionality... :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer to let you know of the option of using smbprotocol; as well as expand in case of misunderstood terminology.

## SMBProtocol Owner Info

It is possible to get the SID using the smbprotocol library as well (just like with the pysmb library).

This was brought up in the [github issues section of the smbprotocol repo](https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/issues/52), along with [an example of how to do it](https://gist.github.com/jborean93/c4d8db1db14297de1c9a268084e89d36). The example provided is fantastic and works perfectly. An extremely stripped down version

However, this also just retrieves a SID and will need a secondary library to perform a lookup.

Here's a function to get the owner SID (just wrapped what's in the gist in a function. Including here in case the gist is deleted or lost for any reason).

```py
import smbclient
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL,NTLM,SUBTREE
def getFileOwner(smb: smbclient, conn: Connection, filePath: str):
    from smbprotocol.file_info import InfoType
    from smbprotocol.open import FilePipePrinterAccessMask,SMB2QueryInfoRequest, SMB2QueryInfoResponse
    from smbprotocol.security_descriptor import SMB2CreateSDBuffer
    
    class SecurityInfo:
        # 100% just pulled from gist example
        Owner = 0x00000001
        Group = 0x00000002
        Dacl = 0x00000004
        Sacl = 0x00000008
        Label = 0x00000010
        Attribute = 0x00000020
        Scope = 0x00000040
        Backup = 0x00010000    
    def guid2hex(text_sid):
        """convert the text string SID to a hex encoded string"""
        s = ['\\{:02X}'.format(ord(x)) for x in text_sid]
        return ''.join(s)
    def get_sd(fd, info):
        """ Get the Security Descriptor for the opened file. """
        query_req = SMB2QueryInfoRequest()
        query_req['info_type'] = InfoType.SMB2_0_INFO_SECURITY
        query_req['output_buffer_length'] = 65535
        query_req['additional_information'] = info
        query_req['file_id'] = fd.file_id

        req = fd.connection.send(query_req, sid=fd.tree_connect.session.session_id, tid=fd.tree_connect.tree_connect_id)
        resp = fd.connection.receive(req)
        query_resp = SMB2QueryInfoResponse()
        query_resp.unpack(resp['data'].get_value())

        security_descriptor = SMB2CreateSDBuffer()
        security_descriptor.unpack(query_resp['buffer'].get_value())

        return security_descriptor

    with smbclient.open_file(filePath, mode='rb', buffering=0,
                         desired_access=FilePipePrinterAccessMask.READ_CONTROL) as fd:
        sd = get_sd(fd.fd, SecurityInfo.Owner | SecurityInfo.Dacl)
        # returns SID
        _sid = sd.get_owner()
    try:
        # Don't forget to convert the SID string-like object to a string
        # or you get an error related to "0" not existing
        sid = guid2hex(str(_sid))
    except:
        print(f"Failed to convert SID {_sid} to HEX")
        raise
    conn.search('DC=dell,DC=com',f"(&(objectSid={sid}))",SUBTREE)    
    # Will return an empty array if no results are found
    return [res['dn'].split(",")[0].replace("CN=","") for res in conn.response if 'dn' in res]
```

to use:

```py
# Client config is required if on linux, not if running on windows
smbclient.ClientConfig(username=username, password=password)

# Setup LDAP session
server = Server('mydomain.com',get_info=ALL,use_ssl = True)
# you can turn off raise_exceptions, or leave it out of the ldap connection
# but I prefer to know when there are issues vs. silently failing
conn = Connection(server, user="domain\username", password=password, raise_exceptions=True,authentication=NTLM)
conn.start_tls()
conn.open()
conn.bind()

# Run the check
fileCheck = r"\\shareserver.server.com\someNetworkShare\someFile.txt"
owner = getFileOwner(smbclient, conn, fileCheck)

# Unbind ldap session
# I'm not clear if this is 100% required, I don't THINK so
# but better safe than sorry
conn.unbind()

# Print results
print(owner)
```

Now, this isn't super efficient. It takes 6 seconds for me to run this one a SINGLE file. So if you wanted to run some kind of ownership scan, then you probably want to just write the program in C++ or some other low-level language instead of trying to use python. But for something quick and dirty this does work. You could also setup a threading pool and run batches. The piece that takes longest is connecting to the file itself, not running the ldap query, so if you can find a more efficient way to do that you'll be golden.

## Terminology Warning, Owner != Creator/Author

Last note on this. Owner != File Author. Many domain environments, and in particular SMB shares, automatically alter ownership from the creator to a group. In my case the results of the above is:
[image]

What I was actually looking for was the creator of the file. File creator and modifier aren't attributes which windows keeps track of by default. An administrator can enable policies to audit file changes in a share, or auditing can be enabled on a file-by-file basis using the Security->Advanced->Auditing functionality for an individual file (which does nothing to help you determine the creator).

That being said, some applications store that information for themselves. For example, if you're looking for Excel [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700294/using-the-author-of-files-to-utilize-the-files-in-python) provides a method for which to get the creator of any xls or xlsx files (doesn't work for xlsb due to the binary nature of the files). Unfortunately few files store this kind of information. In my case I was hoping to get that info for tblu, pbix, and other reporting type files. However, they don't contain this information (which is good from a privacy perspective).

So in case anyone finds this answer trying to solve the same kind of thing I did - Your best bet (to get actual authorship information) is to work with your domain IT administrators to get auditing setup.